# How to avoid that xtable flips the x and y axis of a R table in the final tex output?

Tags: r

I work with xtable which turns a table of r into a functionable latex code.

```
    <<echo=false>>=
attach(warpbreaks)
p2 <- round(tapply(breaks, list(tension), mean), digits=2) %>%
  as.table(.)
@
```

p2 looks like this:

```
  L     M     H 
36.39 26.39 21.67
```

But the output of the created pdf of this code:

```
<<echo=false, results=tex>>=
library("xtable")
xtable(p2,
       align = "rr")
@
```

looks (approximately) like this:

```
      x 
L 36.39 
M 26.39 
H 21.67
```

Why does it not look like the inital table in r and how can I fix it?

Edit: this is the Tex code I get through this

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \hline
 & . \\ 
  \hline
L & 36.39 \\ 
  M & 26.39 \\ 
  H & 21.67 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show a compilable tex code we can play with? Pure r questions are off topic here ...

Comment: @Mensch I made an edit

Answer (score 1):

When you apply `xtable` on objects of type `table` the `xtable.table` method is called. This method is defined as follows (code obtained with `getAnywhere(xtable.table)`):

```r
function (x, caption = NULL, label = NULL, align = NULL, digits = NULL, 
    display = NULL, auto = FALSE, ...) 
{
    if (length(dim(x)) == 1) {
        return(xtable.matrix(matrix(x, dimnames = list(rownames(x), 
            names(dimnames(x)))), caption = caption, label = label, 
            align = align, digits = digits, display = display, 
            auto = auto, ...))
    }
    else if (length(dim(x)) == 2) {
        return(xtable.matrix(matrix(x, ncol = dim(x)[2], nrow = dim(x)[1], 
            dimnames = list(rownames(x), colnames(x))), caption = caption, 
            label = label, align = align, digits = digits, display = display, 
            auto = auto, ...))
    }
    else {
        stop("xtable.table is not implemented for tables of > 2 dimensions")
    }
}
```

So, the table is converted to a matrix and then `xtable` is called on the matrix. When you convert a list to a matrix the values appear in columns:

```
> matrix(p2,dimnames=list(rownames(p2)))
   [,1]
L 36.39
M 26.39
H 21.67
```

To change the output you can transpose the table using `t()`. For this it is not necessary to use `as.table`, you can transpose the result of `tapply` directly.

The transpose function creates a rowname `[1,]` in the output. To remove this you can use `include.rownames=FALSE`. This option is an argument of `print.xtable`, *not* of `xtable` itself. Therefore you need to use the `print` function explicitly in the code.

R code:

```r
p2 <- round(tapply(breaks, list(tension), mean), digits=2)
p2trans <- t(p2)
p2tab <- xtable(p2trans)
print(p2tab,include.rownames=FALSE)
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
attach(warpbreaks)
p2 <- round(tapply(breaks, list(tension), mean), digits=2)
p2trans <- t(p2)
p2tab <- xtable(p2trans)
print(p2tab,include.rownames=FALSE)
@
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]